# Jquery chosen plugin lost style after Spring MVC response

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, spring

I'm using the jQuery plugin chosen.

I have a form where a user can choose from a list of available options. But when i submit the form and reload the div containing the select element, the style is completed lost and the select element become a classic one. After some investigation, i realized that the html contents (before and after the post) differ a lot.

Here are the contents.

Before the submit, this is the html generated

```
<div class="form-group " id="some">
<div>
    <select id="id" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="1">Option1</option>
        <option value="2">Option2</option>
        <option value="3">Option3</option>      
    </select>   

<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 40px; min-width: 0px;" title="" id="id_chosen">
    <a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="chosen-single-content">Select...</span>            
    </a>

    <ul class="chosen-results">
        <li class="active-result result-selected" style="">Select...</li>
        <li class="active-result">Option1</li>
        <li class="active-result">Option2</li>
        <li class="active-result">Option3</li>

    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

after a call to the service, i'm getting back and html code where the content of the div containing the select element is not similar to the initial.

Here it is

```
<div class="form-group " id="wrapper_idrefAddAtcd" style="">
<div>
    <select id="id" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Sélect...</option>
        <option value="1">Option1</option>
        <option value="2">Option2</option>
        <option value="3">Option3</option>      
    </select>
</div>
```

As you can see only the first part of the select elemet is rendered. I don't have any idea where the second part has gone. Can anybody have a clue about what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

After you update the contents of your select element, you need to [trigger an update](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events) event for the plugin to render itself anew.

```
$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: Of course, I tried this but nothing seems to change. The contain of data in this ajax call contains the select element without the desire style.                $.ajax({ 
             type: "POST",
   
             url: my url, success: function(data){        
                alert(data);
             }
         });
    });  When I refresh my page all things is OK.  I can see my select element with the desired style. But when I post the page all my troubles can start then....

Comment: Is this live somewhere?